# ngrx modeling and states

Tags: angular, api, ngrx

If I have a model like this:

```
export interface User {
    id: string;
    email: string;
    someOptional?: string;
}
```

and from the apis I get 2 structures:

```
{
  id: 1,
  email: x@l.com
}
```

and

```
{
  id: 1,
  email: x@l.com,
  someOptional: "something"
}
```

the store is currently having first structure.
now fetching the second structure will cause the store to pull the first structure and not the new "extened version" since it already has it (ofcourse).

how do I over come this?
do I need to create a new state to hold the extened version?

@PierreDuc for comment:
I resolve my route like this

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): 
 Observable<Movie> {

        const movieId = route.params['id'];
        //WORKFLOW: ((6))
        return this.store
          .pipe(
            select(selectMovieById(movieId)),
            tap(movie => {
              if (!movie) {
                this.store.dispatch(new MovieRequested({movieId}));
              }
            }),
            filter(movie => !!movie),
            first()
          )



    }
```

but the selectMovieById(movieId)  returns the movie from the store which has less properties than the MovieRequested({movieId})
so when I move from /movies to movies/123 i wont use MovieRequested({movieId})
but if I refresh movies/123 i get the correct data and the "movies" state holds 1 item only.

should I store this extended version as "currentMovie" state ?

@Християн Христов for comment:

```
export const moviesRoutes: Routes = [
  {
      path: "",
      component: HomeComponent

  },
  {
      path: ':id',
      component: MovieDetailsComponent,
      resolve: {
          movie: MovieResolver
      }
  }
];
```

**SOLUTION: thx to @Християн Христов** 
in the resolver adding

```
this.store.dispatch(new MovieClear());
```

at the start will make the work. and for those who wonder about the MovieClear reducer

```
case MoviesActionTypes.MovieClear:

  return {
    ...state,
    currentMovie: undefined
  }
```

Comment: can you share how you 'fetch' and 'pull' the data into the store?

Comment: Can you show us your route architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to go with the following structure for similar cases

```js
let initialState = {
  id: undefined,
  email: undefined,
  optional: undefined
}
```

This way you will overcome your issue.

Note:
I assume at some point right now you are having some undefined related errors, which are due to accessing an uninitialized fields in the store, but even now if the `optional` parameter is some kind of object, you will still get errors (when accessing some of the object properties). My advice is to make some filtration logic in your streams (look up rxjs  filter operator) , or use the `?` operator in your templates.

## Edit

Ok, i think now i got your problem.

First: You must add `runGuardsAndResolvers` to your path config, so that the resolver is triggered each time you change the route, that is left of the path on which is the resolver or the current (for example if you change the params but stay on the same path)

Second: Add a `new MovieReset()` action wich purpouse is to reset the store state (in other words to clear it)

After you create such action, one way to use it is to dispatch it in the `ngDestroy` hook of the `MovieDetailsComponent`, which will reset the movie wich will make so that resolver will return new film each time it is triggerd.

The other way is pretty much the same but instead to use it in the `onDestroy` hook you can reset the store in the resolver itself and via `switchMap` (after you dispatch the reset action) to return the new value which is saved in the store.

Comment: I use the ngrx adapter.getInitialState , I use the ? operator and have no errors -- NOTE that I have movies screen and after click you go to movie-description screen which has more values and should be from a diffrent api !

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the Reducer you use for the "MovieRequested" action?

In your Reducer you can return your previous state extended with the new data for the "MovieLoaded" action (or how you might call the action that gets the new movie-data).
This might look something like this:

```
switch(action.type) {
   case MovieActionTypes.MOVIE_LOADED: {
      return {
         ...state,
         movies: action.payload
      }
   }
```

The "...state," in this code snipped tells the store to use your previous state and extend it with the following part (movie). Like this you get a state that looks like the following:

```
state = {
   movies: [
      {
         id: 1,
         email: x@l.com
      },
      {
         id: 2,
         email: x@2.com
      }
   ],
   ...
```

If this is what you want (imho it's what the store is for, so you hold all items you requested during the session), you have to adjust your state so that it can hold multiple movies:

```
export interface State {
   isLoading: boolean;
   error: any;
   movies: Array<Movie>;
   ...
}

export const initialMovieState: State = {
   isLoading: false,
   error: "",
   movies: [{
      id: 1,
      email: x@1.com
   }],
   ...
}
```